# APK not getting installed after building using proguard in eclipse

Tags: android, proguard

I build a apk using proguard in release mode.I can see that apk is having less size than normal when I build by running the app.
I moved the apk to my device and try to install it ,it gives me an error as "Application Not Installed."

Comment: Post pro-guard properties

Comment: i have not changed anything in proguard property it is default one that come with adt. I have only included -dontwarn  for twitter and facebook thing.

Comment: i built it as signed application and its getting installed  now.Thanks Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error was cause of mistake I was making , I was building an unsigned version in release mode. Built signed application and it is working now.